# Create a Mysql database by combining the lines of the other two

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I explain you this problem. I need a Mysql query to create Database3, having these 2 databases.

```
DATABASE1:
Url,Company Name,Address,City,ZipCode
www.aaa.com,AAA,StreetAAA,CityAAA,00000
www.bbb.com,BBB,StreetBBB,CityBBB,11111
www.ccc.com,CCC,StreetCCC,CityCCC,22222
www.ddd.com,DDD,StreetDDD,CityDDD,33333
www.eee.com,EEE,StreetEEE,CityEEE,44444
www.fff.com,FFF,StreetFFF,CityFFF,55555

DATABASE2:
Url,Phone
www.aaa.com,0000000000
www.aaa.com,1111111111
www.aaa.com,2222222222
www.bbb.com,3333333333
www.ccc.com,4444444444
www.ccc.com,5555555555
www.ccc.com,6666666666
www.ddd.com,7777777777
www.ddd.com,8888888888
www.eee.com,9999999999
```

I would a final database like this, including PHONE, with repeat all complete information for every phone number, excluding row without phone number:

```
DATABASE3:
Url,Company Name,Address,City,ZipCode,PHONE
www.aaa.com,AAA,StreetAAA,CityAAA,00000,0000000000
www.aaa.com,AAA,StreetAAA,CityAAA,00000,1111111111
www.aaa.com,AAA,StreetAAA,CityAAA,00000,2222222222
www.bbb.com,BBB,StreetBBB,CityBBB,11111,3333333333
www.ccc.com,CCC,StreetCCC,CityCCC,22222,4444444444
www.ccc.com,CCC,StreetCCC,CityCCC,22222,5555555555
www.ccc.com,CCC,StreetCCC,CityCCC,22222,6666666666
www.ddd.com,DDD,StreetDDD,CityDDD,33333,7777777777
www.ddd.com,DDD,StreetDDD,CityDDD,33333,8888888888
www.eee.com,EEE,StreetEEE,CityEEE,44444,9999999999
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below

```
SELECT distinct
b.Url, a.Company Name, a.Address, a.City, a.ZipCode, b.Phone
from 
DATABASE2 b  left outer join DATABASE1 a
On a.Url = b.Url
Where b.Phone IS NOT NULL
Order by b.Phone
```

Comment: Better select `a.url` for a `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports [`create table ... as select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html), which creates a new table based on a query:

```
create table NewTable as
select  t1.Url
,       t1.`Company Name`
,       ...
,       t2.Phone
from    table1 t1
left join
        table2 t2
on      t1.url = t2.url
```